# Properly displaying date in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have encountered a small problem while making a project in ASP.NET Core MVC.

I'm making a car service, where you can make some reservations. Here's the code for my *Customers.cs* in *Models* folder:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}")]
public DateTime CustomerCarDateDayTime { get; set; }
```

On the page in *Create* site I can add new reservation and here is ok I think - the problem occurs when I want to see all the reservations that have been made in *Index*:

[image]

As you can see, the date is not properly displayed on *Index* site.
Under the column of the date there is 01.01.0001 00:00 and not the actual date that was chosen for the reservation.

As far, I have tried modifying the *Customers.cs* to the point that is above. I have also tried modifying the *Index.cshtml* in *Views*

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerCarDateDayTime)
</td>
```

because I thought that maybe the problem with displaying date may be in *View* section, but it didn't helped - as the result of some of my actions, the field became even empty, so I have stopped modifying here.

I was looking for some solutions in Google, some of them I have tried (the results didn't helped much), so in the end I'm still stuck with this.
I'm a self learner, I'm using Visual Studio 2022 for this project.

Due to suggestion, here's my code in *CustomersController.cs*

```
// GET: Customers
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Customers.ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `CustomerCarDateDayTime` is being set correctly? That date looks like the default date/time for DateTime.

Comment: You need to share the code that shows how you are populating the model. Its look like CustomCarDate field is not having any value.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is set correctly - I did this like with strings for getting name, surname etc, sth like this: 
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
but insted of string I wrote DateTime

Comment: You can try to set a default value and test again.`public DateTime SomeProperty { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: @Yiyi You after doing what you suggested, it displayed the current day&time, no matter what you have chosen while making a reservation